# Chinese songs for hiking

Tags: lyrics

What songs do Chinese people sing during hiking? I'm both interested in traditional as well as contemporary songs.

For example, in German there is a song "[The miller's joy is wandering](http://www.lieder.net/lieder/get_text.html?TextId=25554)"

Comment: Chinese marching songs 中文进行曲、行军歌 《军舰进行曲》《义勇军进行曲》  (现为中华人民共和国国歌)

Answer (score 1):

The song that comes vaguely close is 让我们荡起双桨, which describes children rowing boats in a lake after school. This is an 1950s song which almost all mainland Chinese know.
https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%AE%A9%E6%88%91%E4%BB%AC%E8%8D%A1%E8%B5%B7%E5%8F%8C%E6%A1%A8

On the other hand, there are pop songs, eg in this list, but they are not even remotely well known.
https://y.qq.com/portal/playlist/1952753363.html

There are lots of poems about hiking though.

Answer (score 1):

I am a Cantonese native speaker live in Hong Kong and probably we will sing the song of contemporary Canton pop during hiking.

Eason Chan's song are really good in the past decade. You can search for his song in youtube.

For example:
(singer)陳奕迅, eason chan (song name)我的快樂時代
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uWxIAW5gwd4

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. For me as Hongkonger, I hike a lot but never sing. Anyway these lyrics may be related:

- [關正傑: 天蠶變](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JtIpggShheg)
- [Beyond: 歲月無聲](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QEOCahGzR08)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know others ,but I like 《平凡之路》